# How to listen or read past logs event transfer ETH on ERC-20 or (BNB on BSC chain) between two address?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, ethers.js, bsc

I want to listen or get all events transfer native token on Ethereum or BSC networks.

As follow transaction:
https://testnet.bscscan.com//tx/0xe864d268189a0d1397e97f3f896738632c8bcd74d45219b21f7d718f5307a4b1
But I don't know how to setting: parameters: **address**, **topics** in the:

- [web3.eth.subscribe('logs', options [, callback]);](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.4/web3-eth-subscribe.html?highlight=subscribe#subscribe-logs)
- [web3.eth.get_filter_logs(filt.filter_id)](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.get_filter_logs)

  To get only transfer native token ( ETH or BNB ) events
- address: Null
- value > 0
  [image]

Please help me setup parameters to get these events.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need use `eth_getLogs` API for the past events. You do not need to construct filter for it, because filters are stateful functions and only designed for future events.

Another problem is that nodes cannot serve JSON-RPC requests in a scale and you need to be careful when requesting data on different block ranges. [Here is an example Python script how to get past events](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/scripts/read-uniswap-v2-pairs-and-swaps.py).

Comment: I found a bsc scan api, that seem resolve for this problem: https://docs.bscscan.com/api-endpoints/accounts#get-internal-transactions-by-block-range ( Get "Internal Transactions" by Block Range ). Is there any same way to fetch this data with web3 libraries ? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. I linked to an example Python script that does it. Unfortunately I do not have example for web3.js, but the underlying logic is the same.

Answer (score 0):

BNB on BSC or ETH on Ethereum network doesn't emit any events when a transfer is made on them(i.e the native coins does not emits any events when they are sent away or received fron/to a certain address)

But however in other to do that you need to watch any latest(mined) block and iterate through it for any transaction that matches your BNB/ETH address then, record it and process it.

Here is a simple tool written in rust to help you check for BNB/ETH native coins transaction (incoming) for a bunch of addresses you are/want to watch.

https://github.com/ahmadbrainworks/fiddi